# Where to download Nunit documentation other than the main site?

Tags: nunit

The nunit.org website has been down for a while now (over a few days). Does anyone know where I could get the documentation from an alternate site?

Comment: up vote just to be back in 0 as the site is in fact down for a couple of day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is included in the nunit download. A Google for `nunit download` will get you the link to the download on [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/NUnit/3000-2218_4-10962248.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, I was unaware that the downloads were hosted externally. They were so small I made the false assumption that the you downloaded them directly from the website itself.